# how to echo posted JSON data in php

Tags: php

I am trying to display data in php with echo but I do not why it displays nothing when I do it.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$code = mysql_real_escape_string($data->code);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($data->name);

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "thanh03021986")  or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("erp") or die(mysql_error());

echo $name;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO element(`code`, `name` ) VALUES('".$code."','".$name."')");
```

It is obvious that `$name` has value when posted but `echo` display nothing. Also, how can I convert it to php data for use?

Comment: try to print it before mysql_connect. May be error in connection and it goes to die(mysql_error());

Comment: may be file_get_contents('php://input') returns null or blank

Comment: please print_r($data) check the output to confirm value in "name"